# Passando informação entre Framents no Android

Tags: android-fragment

Olá,
Por favor, estou precisando de ajuda.
Estou tentando utilizar o template do Android Studio para fazer um aplicativo simples que em um Fragment (PegaValoresFragment) no método onCreateView pega uma opção de um Spinner que será utilizado no outro Fragment (SegundaFragment).

Para a comunicação entre as duas Fragment tenho uma interface Comunicador e uma MainActivity que implementa Comunicador.

Meu problema está no método onCreateView da PegaValoresFragment. Depois da escolha do Spinner jogo o valor para um atributo estático da classe MainActivity. Esse atributo estático é retornado para a SegundaFragment através de um método getCurso() (esse método está na Interface e implementado na MainActivity).

O problema é que o valor recebido do Spinner que foi colocado no atributo estático da classe MainActivity se perde logo após o final do método onCreateView (return rootView;) da PegaValoresFragment.

A classe MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Comunicador {
public static String vCurso;
public String getCurso() {
    return(MainActivity.vCurso);
}
...
```

A Interface

```
public interface Comunicador{
    String getCurso();
}
```

A classe PegaValoresFragment

```
public class PegaValoresFragment extends Fragment {
...
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    opcoesCurso = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinCurso);
    ArrayAdapter adapterCurso = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.opcoes_cursos,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    opcoesCurso.setAdapter(adapterCurso);

    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener escolhaCurso = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String itemCurso = opcoesCurso.getSelectedItem().toString();

            // PegaValoresFragment.setCurso(itemCurso);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Curso Escolhido foi : "+itemCurso, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    };

    MainActivity.vCurso= opcoesCurso.getSelectedItem().toString();
    ....
    return rootView;
}
...
```

}

A classe SegundaFragment

```
public class SegundaFragment extends Fragment {

Comunicador comm;

public String getCurso(){
    return(comm.getCurso());
}

...

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.segunda_fragment, container, false);
    ...
    String teste = getCurso();

    textView.setText(" Curso getCurso() => "+teste);

    ...
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Por favor, vocês poderiam me ajudar a descobrir onde estou errando?
Obrigado

Comment: Uma das maneiras de resolver isso seria criando uma classe para armazenar esse valor e você teria acesso em qualquer lugar que estiver em seu aplicativo.

Answer (score 0):

Possível solução.

Classe que irá receber os valores solicitados.

```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

   public class GlobalProperties {

   private static GlobalProperties instance = new GlobalProperties();

   public GlobalProperties() {
   }

  public static GlobalProperties getInstance() {
       return instance;
  }

  private String curso;

  public String getCurso() {
     return curso
  }

  public void setCurso(String _curso) {
     this.curso = _curso;
  }
}
```

Classe que recebe o valor do usuário e armazena na classe acima.

```
  public class PegaValoresFragment extends Fragment {


  GlobalProperties gp;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  opcoesCurso = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinCurso);
  ArrayAdapter adapterCurso =       ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.opcoes_cursos,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
opcoesCurso.setAdapter(adapterCurso);

AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener escolhaCurso = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String itemCurso = opcoesCurso.getSelectedItem().toString();

        // PegaValoresFragment.setCurso(itemCurso);

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Curso Escolhido foi : "+itemCurso, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
};
gp = GlobalProperties.getInstance();
gp.setCurso( opcoesCurso.getSelectedItem().toString() );

....
return rootView;
```

}
...

Classe que recebe o valor passado

public class SegundaFragment extends Fragment {

```
GlobalProperties gp;

...

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.segunda_fragment, container, false);
...
gp = GlobalProperties.getInstance();

String teste = gp.getCurso();

textView.setText(" Curso getCurso() => "+teste);

...
return rootView; 
}
```

Comment: Olá Reginaldo. Muito obrigado por sua ajuda, porém está retornando NULL. ("Curso getCurso() => null"). Tentei passar o código do evento onCreateView para o evento onActivityCreated da PegaValoresFragment, mas continua retornando NULL.

Comment: Altere a linha:  gp.setCurso( opcoesCurso.getSelectedItem().toString() );
para : gp.setCurso( "Testando" );

Comment: Muito obrigado. Com esta alteração saiu o Testando.

Comment: O que nos leva a crer que setCurso não esta recebendo uma string adequada. Parece que opcoesCurso.getSelectedItem().toString() não é uma string.

Comment: Oi Reginaldo. Obrigado pela ajuda. Fiz teste atribuindo um valor a um String vCurso = "Teste" e fazendo gp.setCurso(vCurso); Debugando dá para perceber que ao sair do método onCreateView todos os valores são perdidos.

Comment: Também testando descobri que consigo manter os dados no método onCreateView porém neste método ainda não tenho acesso ao Spinner, só terei acesso a ele no próximo método do ciclo de vida da Fragment.

Comment: Tentei passar o valor com atributos estáticos para o onCreateView, sem sucesso. Nas minhas leituras entendi que o método que poderia guardar as informações seria o onSaveInstanceState porém ele não passa por este método. Mais uma vez, obrigado.